# Connecting to clustered SQL Server database

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I am trying to connect to a database using Doctrine in Zend Framework 2 using the PDOMsSql Driver Class:

```
'driverClass' => 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOSqlsrv\Driver',
'params' => array(
    'host'     => 'db-cluster1\database',
    'port'     => '1433',
    'user'     => 'user',
    'password' => 'pass',
    'dbname'   => 'DBName',
```

The problem is, it is set up to use dynamic ports. So, while it’ll be a 1433 connection to SQL Server Browser, it will then be pushed to the dynamic port that the instance is actually listening on. At the moment, this is port 57510 - if I change the port value to that then it connects fine, but I obviously cannot rely on this as it may change.

Does anyone have advice on how to connect this properly to a clustered environment with dynamic ports? Incidentally, I tried just not declaring a port, but this did not work.

Regards
Ryan

Comment: Do you have a way of determining the available ports?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure as it is my customer who is trying to implement the app I created. They know which port it is at the moment and I would assume that there is a range specified. Can you set it up with a range?